# Existence of a subsequence of a sequence which does not converge a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

If the sequence of functions $f_n$ does not converge a.s., show that

there is $\epsilon >0$ and an increasing sequence of integers $n_0< n_1< \cdots <n_k<\cdots $ such that for each $k$, $n_k> 2n_{k-1}$ and
$$\mu \left(\max_{n_{k-1} < n <n_k}\{x\vert \ |f_n-f_{n_{k-1}}\ |>\epsilon \}\right)>\epsilon. $$

My attempts:

For any function $f$, Let $E=\{x|f_n(x)\not \rightarrow f(x)\}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}E_n$, where $E_n=\bigcap_{A\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\ge A}\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)\ge \frac{1}{n}|\}$. We have $0<\mu(E)\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(E_n)$, then $\mu(E_n)\not \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

But I still can not find such a subsequence of $f_n$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Took me a bit to understand the problem. So, you're given a fixed sequence of functions $f_n$ and a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $\mu(\mathcal E)=0$ for $\mathcal E=\{x:\exists y\in\mathbb R\,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=y\}$. I think a good starting point is to show that $\mathcal E$ is measurable. Recall that there are various equivalent criteria for the convergence of sequences, in particular since you may want to get rid of the existence quantifier over an uncountable set.